# Disable checkbox according to the selected option (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a jquery code which aim is to disable/enable group of checkboxes. So far I got: 
Html:

```
<select id="Units">
   <option value="Marketing" > Marketing </option>
   <option value="Finance" > Finance </option>
   <option value="Operations" > Operations </option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox"  class="enable" onclick="check();" value="1"> chbx1
<input type="checkbox"  class="dissable" onclick="check();" value="2"> chbx2
<input type="checkbox"  class="dissable" onclick="check();" value="3"> chbx3
<input type="checkbox"   class="enable" onclick="check();" value="4"> chbx4
```

JS

```
$("#Units").on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).val() !== "Finance") {
    $(".dissable").attr("disabled", "disabled");

} else {
    $(".dissable").removeAttr("disabled");
}
});
```

But it doesn't work properly on the page load. Only after change the selected option the checkboxes react. How to improve this in order to catch selected value when the page is load and enabled/disabled checboxes with apropriate class?

Comment: Trigger the `change` event manually or set initial values in HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".dissable").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$("#Units").on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).val() !== "Finance") {

    $(".dissable").attr("disabled", "disabled");
} else {
    $(".dissable").removeAttr("disabled");
}
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zgn2o40a/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#Units").on("change", function () {
    if ($(this).val() !== "Finance") {
        $(".dissable").prop("disabled", true); // Use prop instead of attr

    } else {
        $(".dissable").prop("disabled", false);
    }
}).trigger('change');
// ^
// This will call function immedietly
```

Comment: Your code will attach `undefined` listener to `change` event

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the change event after defining the event using `.change()` or `.trigger('change')`:

```
$("#Units").on("change", function() {
   //rest code
}).change();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zgn2o40a/)**